# PHP Fast scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

My goal is to collect headtitles from different news outlets and then echo them on my page. I've tried using Simple HTML DOM, and then run an IF statement to check for keywords. It works, but it is very slow! The code is to be found bellow. Is there a better way to go about this, and if so; how would it be written?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

// URL and keyword
$syds = file_get_html('http://www.sydsvenskan.se/nyhetsdygnet');
$syds_key = 'a.newsday__title';

// Debug
$i = 0;

// Checking for keyword "A" in the headtitles
foreach($syds->find($syds_key) as $element) {
   if (strpos($element, 'a') !== false || strpos($element, 'A') !== false) {
      echo $element->href . '<br>';
      $i++;
   }
} 

echo "<h1>$i were found</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: First, try to treat the HTML like an XML document (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Or you can use a library like the Symfony DOM Crawler.

Comment: most news sites have rss feeds, much faster to process them

Comment: Didn't even think of the rss feeds haha, thanks! I will try it out. I will also check out the XML link :)

Comment: If I use a rss feed as a source, it cannot tell if it is the headline or just a word on the rss feed. I only want to search for the keyword in the headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How slow are we talking?**

1-2 seconds would be pretty good.

If your using this for a website.

I'd advise splitting the `crawling` and the `display` into 2 separate scripts, and cache the results of each crawl.

You could:

- have a `crawl.php` file that runs periodically to update your links.
- then have a `webpage.php` that reads the results of the last crawl and displays it however you need for your website.

This way:

- Every time you refresh your webpage, it doesn't re-request info from the news site.
- It's less important that the news site takes a little long to respond.

### Decouple crawling/display

You will want to `decouple`, crawling and display 100%.
Have a "crawler.php" than runs over all the news sites one at a time saving the raw links to a file. This can run every 5-10 minutes to keep the news updated, **be warned** less than 1 minute and some news sites **may** get annoyed!

`crawler.php`

```
<?php
// Run this file from cli every 5-10 minutes
// doesn't matter if it takes 20-30 seconds

require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html_output = ""; // use this to build up html output

$sites = array(
    array('http://www.sydsvenskan.se/nyhetsdygnet', 'a.newsday__title')
    /* more sites go here, like this */
    // array('URL', 'KEY')
);

// loop over each site
foreach ($sites as $site){
   $url = $site[0];
   $key = $site[1];
   // fetch site
   $syds = file_get_html($url);

   // loop over each link
   foreach($syds->find($key) as $element) {
     // add link to $html_output
     $html_output .= $element->href . '<br>\n';
   }
}
// save $html_output to a local file
file_put_contents("links.php", $html_output);
?>
```

`display.php`

```
/* other display stuff here */
<?php
// include the file of links
include("links.php");
?>
```

**Still want faster?**

If you wan't any faster, I'd suggest looking into `node.js`, its much faster at tcp connections and html parsing.

Comment: The more sources I add, the longer it takes and it becomes very annoying. I'll look into splitting it up and using a crawl. Thanks!

Comment: I've added some more info on how to decouple the crawling and display into 2 scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your code. But could you edit it so it would use the code I've written earlier? I'm not sure where to put which. :)

Comment: Do you want a `$syds_key` per site? or just `'a.newsday__title'` for all?

Comment: Yes one key per site, please

Comment: does this make more sense?

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I suppose the links file should be empty? And how do I output the result?

Comment: just like in `display.php`, just include that file in your website where you want the links.

Comment: I have included it just like you did in my index.php file but nothing is showing up.

Comment: have you ran the crawler at least once to populate file? is the file empty? can you write `<h1>Hello world!!</h1>` in the `links.php` save then refresh, do you see anything?

Comment: Totally forgot about the crawler haha. How do I run the crawler on an interval?

Comment: thought you may ask, google `crontab`, its the tool for the job.... don't forget to mark the question answered :D

Comment: When I make a duplicate of the array() to add more websites, it gives me an error in the crawler... :/

Comment: have you missed a `,` between the 2 arrays?

Comment: That was it haha!

Answer (score 0):

The bottlenecks are:

- blocking IO - you can switch to an asynchronous library like [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)
- parsing - you can switch to a [different parser](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) for better parsing speed